# Laravel 5.2 - Make different Read/Write Connections

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, database-connection

In laravel 5.2, we wanted to have different connections for read/write, so I followed the advice as provided in laravel documents. But, by default, it was only creating default **mysql** named connection and not 2 different **read/write** connections, therefore it was picking the **read** connection for operations like **INSERT/UPDATE**.

After debugging, it was found that in **DatabaseManager.php** file the connection named passed as argument to `makeconnection()` was **mysql** and not **mysql::read or mysql::write**.

**Before**

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            //we need to have this nested options for both read/write 
            'read' => [
                'host' => env('DB_READ_HOST'),
            ],
            'write' => [
                'host' => env('DB_WRITE_HOST'),                  
            ],
              'host' => env('DB_READ_HOST'),
              'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
              'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
              'driver'    => 'mysql',
              'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
              'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
              'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
              'charset'   => 'utf8',
              'prefix'    => '',
              'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

File - `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php`

```
public function connection($name = null)
    {
        list($name, $type) = $this->parseConnectionName($name);

        // If we haven't created this connection, we'll create it based on the config
        // provided in the application. Once we've created the connections we will
        // set the "fetch mode" for PDO which determines the query return types.
        if (! isset($this->connections[$name])) {
            $connection = $this->makeConnection($name);

            $this->setPdoForType($connection, $type);

            $this->connections[$name] = $this->prepare($connection);
        }

        return $this->connections[$name];
    }
```

So, we have added a small change in the file, after adding this, it's now creating two different connections **mysql.read/mysql.write** and switching them appropriately according to the given sql operations **SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE**

Needed you feedback if this is a viable solution ?

**After changing the file**

`config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
    //we need to have this nested options for both read/write 
    'read' => [
        'host' => env('DB_READ_HOST'),
        'username'  => env('DB_READ_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => env('DB_READ_PASSWORD'),
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => env('DB_WRITE_HOST'),
        'username'  => env('DB_WRITE_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => env('DB_WRITE_PASSWORD'), 
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,

    ],
      'host' => env('DB_READ_HOST'),
      'username'  => env('DB_READ_USERNAME'),
      'password'  => env('DB_READ_PASSWORD'),
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
      'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
      'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
      'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
      'charset'   => 'utf8',
      'prefix'    => '',
      'strict'    => false,
],
```

File - `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php`

```
public function connection($name = null)
{
    list($name, $type) = $this->parseConnectionName($name);
    // we check if the $type is read/write and store appropriate connections
    if( $type != null ) {
        $name .= '.' . $type;
    }
    //end

    // If we haven't created this connection, we'll create it based on the config
    // provided in the application. Once we've created the connections we will
    // set the "fetch mode" for PDO which determines the query return types.
    if (! isset($this->connections[$name])) {
        $connection = $this->makeConnection($name);

        $this->setPdoForType($connection, $type);

        $this->connections[$name] = $this->prepare($connection);
    }

    return $this->connections[$name];
}
```